# verify password function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The verify password function will return false if password is less than 3 and greater than 20 in length and also when both passwords don't match. Please could someone guide me in understanding why my logic below is failing and show me a better way of doing this?

```
def verifyPassword(password, password2):
    if(len(password) == len(password2):
        if(len(password) and len(password2) >= 3:
            if(len(password) and len(password2) < 20:
                if password == password:
                    return True
                else:                
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        False
print(verifyPassword("le3ather", "leather2"))
print(verifyPassword("leather", "leather2"))
print(verifyPassword("leather", "leather"))
print(verifyPassword("le", "Le"))
print(verifyPassword("leatherLeatherleather", "leatherLeatherleather"))
```

Comment: The indentation is clearly wrong in your code. Please fix that first.

Comment: When does your code fails? In which cases?

Comment: `(password == password2) and (3 <= len(password) <= 20)`

Comment: Please update your question with details on what is going wrong. e.g. what you expect and what you are getting

Comment: You are looping through every letter in password2 for every letter in password, but running the exact operations as the index `count` never changes and is always 0. You need "return False", not "False".

Fix indentation. Don't use semicolons (;).

To compare strings use `password == password2`. No for loops necessary.

Your comparison is all wrong, do `3 < len(password) < 20`. However, this is bad practice. Passwords need to be much longer than 3 chars, and why limit to 20?

Comment: you are right now understand where i went wrong and to fix it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what you are exactly aiming, but here is what I made for you:
https://gist.github.com/dgsbicak/96517f33e516ca4438c6e252149b8cbc

```
def verifyPassword(password, password2):
    count = 0
    # Rule 1
    pas = [password, password2]
    for p in pas:
        if len(p)<3:
            print("Password length is shorter than 3")
            break
        elif len(p)>19:
            print("Password length is longer than 19")
            break
        else: pass


    if password==password2:
        return "Password is correct"
    else:
        return "Password is not correct"

print(verifyPassword("le3ather", "leather2"))
print(verifyPassword("leather", "leather2"))
print(verifyPassword("leather", "leather"))
print(verifyPassword("le", "Le"))
print(verifyPassword("leatherLeatherleather", "leatherLeatherleather"))
```

Comment: This helps a lot. it does exactly what i expected. I guess i was thinking of it all wrong. i never thought to put both strings into a new list to compare them. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your welcome, I would very much appreciate if you could select this answer as helpful. Have a good day.

Comment: It would be better to include the code in the answer. Links can break.

Comment: Thanks for adjustments.

Comment: Why check the length of both passwords? They have to be identical anyway, so they can't reasonably be of different length then.

Answer (score 0):

```
MINLEN = 3
MAXLEN = 20

def verifypassword(pw1, pw2):
    if pw1 != pw2:
        return False
    if len(pw1) < MINLEN:
        return False
    if len(pw1) > MAXLEN:
        return False

    return True


def test():
    tests = [
            ("le3ather", "leather2"),
            ("leather", "leather2"),
            ("leather", "leather"),
            ("le", "le"),
            ("thisiseverybittoolong", "thisiseverybittoolong"),
    ]
    for p1, p2 in tests:
        print(p1, p2, verifypassword(p1, p2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score -1):

This

```
if((len(password) == len(password2)) and (len(password) and len(password2)) >= 3 < 20 ):
```

should probably be this

```
if((len(password) == len(password2)) and (len(password) and len(password2)) >= 3 and (len(password) and len(password2)) < 20 ):
```

Though I'm sure there is a simpler way, that seemed like the smallest change to your code.

Comment: @ScottHunter how's that?

Comment: @ScottHunter yea it's working for me as expected in Ipython